# Ошибка импорта модуля зависимости при запуске теста на Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jest

У меня есть приложение на node.js в котором я использую библиотеку P-queue для формирования внутренних очередей исполнения.

Решил покрыть свой код unit тестами на Jest

Вот код теста, тут нет пока никакой логики, просто для понимания покрытия

```
import { queuePaused, queueClear } from './../../modules/queue/fnc.js'

describe('Работа с очередями', () => {
  test('1', () => {
    expect(queueClear('name')).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
 FAIL  __tests__/queue/fnc.test.js                     
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    C:\Develop\roadmap\server\node_modules\p-queue\dist\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import EventEmitter from 'eventemitter3';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 1 | import PQueue from 'p-queue';
        | ^
      2 | import config from '../config.js'
      3 | import os from 'os';
      4 |

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1728:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (modules/queue/index.js:1:1)
```

Как видно из ошибки, Jest не смог заимпортить модуль EventEmitter из внутренней зависимости.

Кто знает, как это можно побороть? Есть идеи?

Версии пакетов:

```
'p-queue': '7.1.0', 'jest': 27.5.1'
```

Comment: Что за `fnc.js`, что в нем написано? Мне интересны что делают эти ваши функции `queuePaused`, `queueClear`.

Comment: @Randall Эти функции ставят очередь на паузу и чистят очереди. Но в данном случае до них дело не доходит. Ошибка возникает на строке `import PQueue from 'p-queue';`

Comment: Да, вы правы. Моя невнимательность. Можете поделиться версиями пакетов?

Comment: @Randall Добавил версии

Comment: Можете добавить эту конфигурацию в `jest.config.js` файл и проверить ```moduleNameMapper: {
  '^p-queue': '[путь к модулю внутри node_modules]'
}```